# IIS7.5 Application Request Routing for multiple sites on one WebFarm

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, iis-7.5, web-farm

I am running some test scenarios with setting up a server farm using Windows 2008R2, IIS7.5, WebFarm Framework and Application Request Routing.

I have three servers:

```
WebFarm1    Controller    192.168.0.231
WebFarm2    Primary       192.168.0.232
WebFarm3    Secondary     192.168.0.233
```

Using just the default site on all three servers I can successfully browser to http://192.168.0.231 and it will load balance between WebFarm2 and WebFarm3.

I would like to setup the WebFarm so that it can replace an existing server that runs multiple sites with different bindings. For example:

```
TestServer1    TestSite1    192.168.0.241    D:\Sites\TestSite1\
TestServer1    TestSite2    192.168.0.242    D:\Sites\TestSite2\
TestServer1    TestSite3    192.168.0.243    D:\Sites\TestSite3\
```

How would I configure the WebFarm to do this?

- Which Server do I add the three IP addresses to? I would guess at WebFarm1
- I can create the three sites on WebFarm2 but how can I set up the bindings if it doesn't have the IP addresses?
- Do I need to create the three sites on WebFarm1 as well?

Can anyone help or point me somewhere with any articles?